# Detect closure of android app

Tags: android

I've 22 different activities in my android, they all inherit from one custom activity. Theoretically they all can be launched in one time. How can detect then user minimizes or closes the app?

I know about Activity Lifecycles and `onStop()` callback. Is there no nicer way, than writing a manager that listens all the `onStop()` callbacks from activities?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, yes.  I would add an onPause() listener.  Unless you need to know exactly which activity is being minimized/closed I would only add the interface into the parent custom activity; so you only have to write the code once.

Hope this helps :)